# How to convert from full-width to half-width Japanese characters in Java?

Tags: java, encoding, character

I'm using class [Transliterator](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/Transliterator.html) of the icu project to convert from half-width to full-width characters like this:

```
Transliterator transliterator = Transliterator.getInstance("Hiragana-Katakana");
String converted = transliterator.transliterate("ｺﾝﾆﾁﾊ");  //half-width
```

The result of `converted` is: コンニチハ  (full-width)

But:

```
String converted = transliterator.transliterate("コンニチハ");  //full-width
```

The result of `converted` is still: コンニチハ  (full-width)

My expectation is `ｺﾝﾆﾁﾊ`. Can anyone help me solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: but `コンニチハ` is already Katakana

Comment: yes I think the func know that is a full-width and expect it outputs a half-width, but it did not.

Comment: I have no idea about Japanese characters, but wouldn't you need a reverse transliterator (`Katakana-Hiragana`)? Sorry if that's a stupid suggestion.

Comment: There are no half-width hiragana, but you gave me a hint for this. That's simply use another parameter. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer [here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-are-the-system-transliterators-available-with-icu4j.html). It's so simple by using different params as below:

```
Transliterator transliterator = Transliterator.getInstance("Halfwidth-Fullwidth");
String converted = transliterator.transliterate("ｺﾝﾆﾁﾊ");  //half-width
```

`converted` value: コンニチハ

```
Transliterator transliterator = Transliterator.getInstance("Fullwidth-Halfwidth");
String converted = transliterator.transliterate("コンニチハ");  //full-width
```

`converted` value: ｺﾝﾆﾁﾊ