# Formatting issues with Japanese chars

Tags: java

We need to Printing to CONSOLE in TABLE format using both English and Japanese. However we are seeing different formatting issues with the Japanese chars. If we use the English it is working fine.
We have searched different solutions but all are working fine with the english but failing for the Japanese chars.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    simpleTable();
  }

  public static void simpleTable() {

    /*
     * leftJustifiedRows - If true, it will add "-" as a flag to format string to make it left
     * justified. Otherwise right justified.
     */
    boolean leftJustifiedRows = false;

    /*
     * Table to print in console in 2-dimensional array. Each sub-array is a row.
     */
    String[][] english = new String[][] {
        {"Entity", "Total", "Extracted", "Validated", "Errors", "Migration", "Errors"},
        {"Device", "John", "Johnson", "45", "", "", ""},
        {"Device Groups", "Tom", "", "35", "", "", ""},
        {"Policies", "Rose", "Johnson", "22", "", "", ""},
        {"Deployments", "Jimmy", "Kimmel", "", "", "", ""},
        {"Duration", "Jimmy", "Kimmel", "", "", "", ""}};
    dispaly(leftJustifiedRows, english);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    String[][] japanese = new String[][] {
        {"\u30A8\u30F3\u30C6\u30A3\u30C6\u30A3", "\u5408\u8A08", "\u62BD\u51FA",
            "\u691C\u8A3C\u6E08\u307F", "\u30A8\u30E9\u30FC", "\u79FB\u884C\u6E08\u307F",
            "\u30A8\u30E9\u30FC"},
        {"\u30c7\u30d0\u30a4\u30b9", "John", "Johnson", "45", "", "", ""},
        {"\u30C7\u30D0\u30A4\u30B9\u30B0\u30EB\u30FC\u30D7", "Tom", "", "35", "", "", ""},
        {"\u30dd\u30ea\u30b7\u30fc", "Rose", "Johnson", "22", "", "", ""},
        {"\u30c7\u30d7\u30ed\u30a4\u30e1\u30f3\u30c8", "Jimmy", "Kimmel", "", "", "", ""},
        {"\u671f\u9593", "Tom", "", "35", "", "", ""}};
    dispaly(leftJustifiedRows, japanese);


  }

  private static void dispaly(boolean leftJustifiedRows, String[][] table) {
    /*
     * Calculate appropriate Length of each column by looking at width of data in each column.
     * 
     * Map columnLengths is <column_number, column_length>
     */
    Map<Integer, Integer> columnLengths = new HashMap<>();
    Arrays.stream(table)
        .forEach(a -> Stream.iterate(0, (i -> i < a.length), (i -> ++i)).forEach(i -> {
          if (columnLengths.get(i) == null) {
            columnLengths.put(i, 0);
          }
          if (columnLengths.get(i) < a[i].length()) {
            columnLengths.put(i, a[i].length());
          }
        }));
    System.out.println("columnLengths = " + columnLengths);

    /*
     * Prepare format String
     */
    final StringBuilder formatString = new StringBuilder("");
    String flag = leftJustifiedRows ? "-" : "";
    columnLengths.entrySet().stream()
        .forEach(e -> formatString.append("| %" + flag + e.getValue() + "s "));
    formatString.append("|\n");
    System.out.println("formatString = " + formatString.toString());

    /*
     * Print table
     */
    Stream.iterate(0, (i -> i < table.length), (i -> ++i))
        .forEach(a -> System.out.printf(formatString.toString(), table[a]));
  }
}
```

[image: Output]

---

**Edit2:**

I have updated code as shown below:

```
Transliterator transliterator = Transliterator.getInstance("Halfwidth-Fullwidth");
    Stream.iterate(0, (i -> i < table.length), (i -> ++i))
        .forEach(a -> System.out.print(transliterator.transliterate(String.format(formatString.toString(), table[a]))));
```

still facing the issue:

[image: new]

Comment: This is an issue of characters not being the same width for both ascii and Japanese characters. Something you could try to do is convert all the characters to full-width before printing them, that way, everything is at least the same width. Perhaps this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32303509/how-to-convert-from-full-width-to-half-width-japanese-characters-in-java

Comment: Tried but facing the same alignment issues

Comment: I have added Half to Full Width converter for all the Japanese chars. e.g. `String[][] japanese = new String[][] {
      {transliterator.transliterate("\u30A8\u30F3\u30C6\u30A3\u30C6\u30A3"), transliterator.transliterate("\u5408\u8A08"), transliterator.transliterate("\u62BD\u51FA"),
        transliterator.transliterate("\u691C\u8A3C\u6E08\u307F"), transliterator.transliterate("\u30A8\u30E9\u30FC"), transliterator.transliterate("\u79FB\u884C\u6E08\u307F"),
          transliterator.transliterate("\u30A8\u30E9\u30FC")}`,....etc.

Comment: Oh, no. I wouldn't do it there. The only way to ensure everything is equal is to full-width everything. Instead of using `printf` directly, use `System.out.print(transliterator.transliterate(String.format(formatString.toString(), table[a])))`

Comment: I have modified the code as per the suggestion still we have alignment issue.
Transliterator transliterator = Transliterator.getInstance("Halfwidth-Fullwidth");
    Stream.iterate(0, (i -> i < table.length), (i -> ++i))
        .forEach(a -> System.out.print(transliterator.transliterate(String.format(formatString.toString(), table[a]))));

｜　　　エンティティ　｜　　　　合計　｜　　　　　　抽出　｜　検証済み　｜　エラー　｜　移行済み　｜　エラー　｜
｜　　　　　デバイス　｜　　Ｊｏｈｎ　｜　Ｊｏｈｎｓｏｎ　｜　　　４５　｜　　　　　｜　　　　　　｜　　　　　｜
｜　デバイスグループ　｜　　　Ｔｏｍ　｜　　　　　　　　　｜　　　３５　｜　　　　　｜　　　　　　｜　　　　　｜
｜　　　　　ポリシー　｜　　Ｒｏｓｅ　｜　Ｊｏｈｎｓｏｎ　｜　　　２２　｜　　　　　｜　　　　　　｜　　　　　｜

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113534/monospace-font-that-supports-both-english-and-japanese (Source Han Sans). Though best to use an HTML `<table>`. Also be aware that Japanese needs a bit larger font size.

Comment: Unfortunately I’m looking for the solution on the CLI not on the GUI.

Comment: This output is correct. Now it's up to whatever the user is using for text display and the font being used. At this point, the best course of action may be to recommend that your users get the font that @JoopEggen has suggested. How will this application be used? Also, for code updates, please keep those in edits to your question as the comments do not format those, and it just ends up adding noise.

Comment: We will be running our application in the command line I.e either in command prompt or putty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use zero-width characters (ex: U+200C) to adjust the length of the string to the width of the string.

```java
package org.example;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    simpleTable();
  }

  public static void simpleTable() {

    /*
     * leftJustifiedRows - If true, it will add "-" as a flag to format string to make it left
     * justified. Otherwise right justified.
     */
    boolean leftJustifiedRows = false;

    /*
     * Table to print in console in 2-dimensional array. Each sub-array is a row.
     */
    String[][] english = new String[][] {
        {"Entity", "Total", "Extracted", "Validated", "Errors", "Migration", "Errors"},
        {"Device", "John", "Johnson", "45", "", "", ""},
        {"Device Groups", "Tom", "", "35", "", "", ""},
        {"Policies", "Rose", "Johnson", "22", "", "", ""},
        {"Deployments", "Jimmy", "Kimmel", "", "", "", ""},
        {"Duration", "Jimmy", "Kimmel", "", "", "", ""}};
    dispaly(leftJustifiedRows, english);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    String[][] japanese = new String[][] {
        {"\u30A8\u30F3\u30C6\u30A3\u30C6\u30A3", "\u5408\u8A08", "\u62BD\u51FA",
            "\u691C\u8A3C\u6E08\u307F", "\u30A8\u30E9\u30FC", "\u79FB\u884C\u6E08\u307F",
            "\u30A8\u30E9\u30FC"},
        {"\u30c7\u30d0\u30a4\u30b9", "John", "Johnson", "45", "", "", ""},
        {"\u30C7\u30D0\u30A4\u30B9\u30B0\u30EB\u30FC\u30D7", "Tom", "", "35", "", "", ""},
        {"\u30dd\u30ea\u30b7\u30fc", "Rose", "Johnson", "22", "", "", ""},
        {"\u30c7\u30d7\u30ed\u30a4\u30e1\u30f3\u30c8", "Jimmy", "Kimmel", "", "", "", ""},
        {"\u671f\u9593", "Tom", "", "35", "", "", ""}};
    dispaly(leftJustifiedRows, japanese);


  }

  private static void dispaly(boolean leftJustifiedRows, String[][] table) {

      /// ADD ZERO-WIDTH CHARACTERS TO STRINGS ///
      try {
          for (int i=0; i<table.length; i++) {
              for (int j=0; j<table[i].length; j++) {
                  // Get the number of code points
                  int length = table[i][j].length();
                  // Get the width of the string
                  // Windows-31J (Shift-JIS) uses 1 byte for half-width characters
                  // and 2 bytes for full-width characters
                  int width = table[i][j].getBytes("Windows-31J").length;
                  // Add one zero-width character for each full-width character
                  table[i][j] = table[i][j] + "\u200C".repeat(width - length);
              }
          }
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
      /// ADD ZERO-WIDTH CHARACTERS TO STRINGS ///

    /*
     * Calculate appropriate Length of each column by looking at width of data in each column.
     *
     * Map columnLengths is <column_number, column_length>
     */
    Map<Integer, Integer> columnLengths = new HashMap<>();
    Arrays.stream(table)
        .forEach(a -> Stream.iterate(0, (i -> i < a.length), (i -> ++i)).forEach(i -> {
          if (columnLengths.get(i) == null) {
            columnLengths.put(i, 0);
          }
          if (columnLengths.get(i) < a[i].length()) {
            columnLengths.put(i, a[i].length());
          }
        }));
    System.out.println("columnLengths = " + columnLengths);

    /*
     * Prepare format String
     */
    final StringBuilder formatString = new StringBuilder("");
    String flag = leftJustifiedRows ? "-" : "";
    columnLengths.entrySet().stream()
        .forEach(e -> formatString.append("| %" + flag + e.getValue() + "s "));
    formatString.append("|\n");
    System.out.println("formatString = " + formatString.toString());

    /*
     * Print table
     */
    Stream.iterate(0, (i -> i < table.length), (i -> ++i))
        .forEach(a -> System.out.printf(formatString.toString(), table[a]));
  }
}
```

You will get the result like this (on the console tab in Eclipse)

[image: Screenshot]

#### Restrictions:

- Your terminal needs to be able to handle Unicode characters.
- The Japanese characters in the table don't contain surrogate pairs.